# Maximum memory allocation for 32bit linux kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, kernel

I was reading this article that talks about how maximum amount of ram dedicated for kernel usage in 32 bit windows is 2GB even when the total amount of ram is >4GB.

http://www.brianmadden.com/blogs/brianmadden/archive/2004/02/19/the-4gb-windows-memory-limit-what-does-it-really-mean.aspx\

1. Is this the same for 32bit linux environments like 32-bit ubuntu
   10.04? IE is the max kernel allocation 2GB ram even if the total main memory >4GB?
2. If you increase the total amount of memory to 64GB of ram by
   recompiling the kernel with the PAE option enabled, what is the
   maximum amount of ram you can dedicate for kernel usage?  Is it
   still 2GB?  Or can you increase it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both kernels split the virtual address space into a user portion and a kernel portion.  The kernel portion is shared between all processes in the system, and so the kernel is limited to that much directly addressable memory.  Each user process in the system has its own user portion of the address space.  Classically this split was done in the middle, giving each half 2gb.  Windows can be directed to move the split to 3gb for user and 1gb for kernel with the /3gb boot.ini switch.  The linux kernel is rather configurable at build time, and last I checked, the Ubuntu kernels build with the 3:1 split.

PAE allows for 64 gb of physical ram to be addressed, but any given page table still is limited to 4gb.  Because there is only one kernel portion of that address space shared between all processes on the system, it is limited to 1 or 2 GB of directly addressable ram no matter what.  Additional physical memory can be used, but it has to be only partially mapped into the virtual address space at any given time, and the mappings changed when needed.  Because each process has a separate user address space, you can have, for example, 5 different processes that each have 2gb of their own memory that maps to different parts of 16gb of physical ram you have installed, and the kernel using another 2gb.

Note that the filesystem cache does not have to keep pages mapped all the time, so it can use plenty more of that physical ram, and the kernel automatically maps bits of it when needed, then unmaps it so it can map other pages.  This trickery allows the kernel to use many gb of memory for the cache, and a few hundred mb for other uses, even when the kernel only has 1gb of virtual address space to play with.

Also worth noting is that in recent versions of Windows, Microsoft has instituted various artificial product licensing limitations.  The Windows 7 Pro I am stuck with on my PC at work refuses to use physical ram addresses > 4gb even if I enable PAE, which results in it only being able to use 3.4 of the 4.0 gb of ram installed, since a chunk of the ram is relocated over the 4gb mark to leave room for things like the video ram to be located under 4gb.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the reason windows can't allocate all the memory is because some of that memory space is used for Video Ram.

As for your question about PAE I'm not sure.  If you had 64GB ram and PAE you could probably use more than 4 gigs in total, but I think each individual program would be limited to 4 gigs ram.

This problem comes from the address space provided by a 32 bit integer.  2^32 provides 4294967295 values, hence 4 gig ram limit.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this text](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory), Linux splits at 3G, so you are supposed to have access to 3G of RAM at once, as you have with Windows with the [/3GB switch applied to the boot.ini](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833721).

At least, in theory. Due to some reason unknown to me, a test just has proven that I only can use a part of this memory:

```
08048000-0804b000 data?
0804b000-081ce000 heap
65e00000-b7395000 mmap-ed heap
b7395000-b73ac000 mmap-ed code
bf93f000-bf960000 stack
```

Why I couldn't `malloc()` the range from `081ce000-65e00000`, I don't know.

Comment: Linux has multiple options for its split: 2G/2G; 3G/1G; and even a special 4G/4G split where user and kernel each get just shy of 4GB per process (at a slight performance cost).